# How do I keep div columns with different heights aligned?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, row, multiple-columns

Ok, so I am coding a WordPress site and as we all know, you only need to enter the CSS / HTML once and WordPress repeats it for every post.

I have 6 `inline-block` `<div>`'s, 3 columns and 2 rows. Now, if the text in one of the `<div>`'s is long, it stretches the height of the div. That pushes the `<div>` under that one way down.

How can I get it so that the row under that `<div>` is not affected by the height of one or all of the `<div>`'s above it?

I read some suggestions suggesting the use of `display: flex`, but I don't understand it and it seems to always mess things up for me.

Also, `vertical-align: top` doesn't work either.

Here is what the site looks like now:

[image: sceenshot]

How do I get this fixed?

The `<div>` selector's name is "fourth-post" and it's wrapped in the `<div>` "container"

Here is the relevant CSS:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fourth-post{
    max-width: 410px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.fourth-post:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    clear: left;
}
```

and here is my html I just copied and pasted it four times.

```
 <div id="container">
 <div class="fourth-post">
 <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
 <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
<p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To.     </p>
  <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
```

Is there any other solution besides `display: flex` or Masonry or anything involving jQuery?

Here is a link to the site as well ----> http://GetVersed.us

Comment: Add your `HTML` also

Comment: I thought you weren't looking for a flexbox solution? And by saying you didn't want to use jQuery, I assumed that also included javascript. The solution you chose is flexbox and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#flexWrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#flexWrapper >div {
  max-width: 410px;
  padding: 10px
}
#flexWrapper >div >img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and this `javaScript` ...

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    flexWrapper = document.createElement("div"),
    firstFourth = document.querySelector('.fourth-post');

flexWrapper.id = 'flexWrapper';
container.insertBefore(flexWrapper, firstFourth);

var fourths = document.querySelectorAll('#flexWrapper ~ .fourth-post');

[].forEach.call(fourths, function(fourth){
   flexWrapper.appendChild(fourth);
});
```

will fix your problem. What the `js` does is grab all your `.fourt-post`s and place them into a dynamically created container, since adding `display:flex` to your current container will cause too much extra effort.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    flexWrapper = document.createElement("div"),
    firstFourth = document.querySelector('.fourth-post');
    
flexWrapper.id = 'flexWrapper';
container.insertBefore(flexWrapper, firstFourth);

var fourths = document.querySelectorAll('#flexWrapper ~ .fourth-post');

[].forEach.call(fourths, function(fourth){
   flexWrapper.appendChild(fourth);
});
```

```css
#flexWrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#flexWrapper > div {
  max-width: 410px;
  padding: 10px
}
#flexWrapper > div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="first-post">first post</div>
  <div class="second-post">second post</div>
  <div class="second-post">second post</div>
  <div class="third-post">third post</div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/410/320">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... will fix your issue.

Please note you should prefix your CSS using [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) (set to `> 0%` - small setting at the bottom - for maximum browser compatibility - 97.5%).

Comment: *"Is there any other solution besides display: flex or Masonry or anything involving jQuery?" - OP*

Comment: Of course there is: `display:table;` FTW!. Web means displaying data according to some specs. If the code I provide does this, it could as well be written in any language, using any technology. I happen not to agree with your solution of helping them "fix" a solution that's not responsive only because they're not aware of that just yet.

Comment: This worked for that issue but caused problems with my other floating elements, I'm about to try to fix those

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with any such problems and i'll be happy to assist with both fixing and explaining the principle.

Comment: Ok  I will make a gist.....But if you go to http://GetVersed.us from a computer you will see at the top, where it says "Chance The Rapper" the photo that's under that photo is suppose to be aligned right. But I will post a link to the gist. I have tried fixing some things myself. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: So I take it you have no control over your markup? You can't group all `.fourth-post`s into one container. Is this correct?

Comment: @TerrellAnderson See the updated answer. You're right, adding `flexbox` to your container creates too much extra work. So the simple way to go about it is to place the elements we want wrapped in flex inside a dynamically added element. Let me know if it works. You probably don't want the `padding` and other details I added just so it displays decently here, on SO.

Comment: You're suggesting `> 0%` for maximum CSS compatibility, but at the same time you use some of the not so compatible JavaScript methods.

Comment: @Koen. I'm not as versed in `JavaScript`. Happy to hear suggestions. What are you referring to and is there any documentation I could peruse on the matter? Always happy to learn (that's what I like about SO).

Comment: Just saying that the `> 0%` probably also includes IE8, which doesn't have the `forEach` method.

Comment: @Koen. [`Nope`](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Microsoft dropped support for IE8 about an year ago. That basically means all its usage traffic currently comes from website owners checking to see if their website works in it. I've literally shown the door to all clients asking for IE8 coverage for their website over the past 6 months. None actually went out the door. They just dropped the request.

Comment: This `FLEX` stuff is horrendous it makes everything more complicated, simple floating ellements wont even work...sheesh lol

Comment: Don't use it where you don't need it, @TerrellAnderson. It's not solution to anything and I certainly do not use it everywhere. Use containers. Have you tried the `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You only want to apply `margin-right: 0;` to `:nth-child(3)`, then you want to apply `clear: left;` to `:nth-child(4)` so that it clears the left side and ensures that float will start on a cleared row.

But using `3n` and `4n` with `:nth-child()` will repeat every 3rd/4th child, in case you choose to add more elements down the road.

And no need for `inline-block` on `.fourth-post`. When you `float` an element, it makes it `block`, so the `inline-block` isn't doing anything.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fourth-post {
  max-width: 410px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.fourth-post:nth-child(4n) {
  clear: left;
}

.fourth-post:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-post">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/getversedmagazine/foundation/img/jaden.png">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Jaden Smith Joins Shia LaBeouf In 4 Year Long Trump      Protest jkgljvnlsk kvnlkgnkls jbglnldsd</h2>
    <p>Jaden Smith, son of Will and boxed-water enthusiast, has been in Shia Labeouf’s corner since at least 2014, when he tweeted that he needed to speak to LaBeouf to tell him, “I’m Here If You Need A Fellow Insane Person To Talk To. </p>
    <div class="author-date">By: Terrell Anderson • 6 hours ago</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TerrellAnderson can you post your HTML structure then and reproduce it for us in your post? Does my demo work for you?

Comment: This actually pushed the other two post down to the second row, leaving the first post to stand alone and pushed the other two post in the second down creating two more rows. That's when i used `(3n)/(4n)` but when I used`(3)/(4)` it went back to looking like the photo above, @Michael

Comment: @TerrellAnderson ***can you post your HTML structure then and reproduce it for us in your post? Does my demo work for you?*** Give us a [mcve]

Comment: Just added the minimal html. @MichaelCoker

Comment: @TerrellAnderson that doesn't reproduce the problem. Updated my answer with your HTML and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "inline-block" elements, you shouldn't use "float" property, because "inline-block" makes elemets follow each other one by one with wrapping  to the new line if there lack of space. Beside that, "vertical-align" property doesn't work with "float" if you don't set a "line-height", but I think it is more about some "one-line" blocks. Also, there is a small piece of math that helps you to controll margin (see the stylesheet).

You need to remember, that if element has property "float" and it set as "left" or "right":

- the element displays like it has "display:block" property.
- the element shrinks in width to the size of its content, if it has no explicitly set "width" property
- the element sticks to the left or right side
- everything that follows the element, wraps it around

To set or unset margin of particular element(s) you can use "
:nth-child(math)" pseudo-selector.

Also you can use that small js script, that makes the height of choosen elements the same regardet to biggest one.

```css
.container {
    max-width:1280px;
    /* Just to make it centered*/
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
  .child {
    /* "inline-block" makes divs follow each other one by one */
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:410px;
    width:410px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right:1%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: red;
    /* *
    *  You can use "vertical-align" if you want and it works as expected
    */
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  /* *
  *  this rule adds the top margin for elements that are not in the first line
  *  lets var i = number of elements in the row
  *  so the principe of rule is: .elem:nth-child(n + (i+1))
  */
  .child:nth-child(n+4) {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  /* * 
  *  This code just change height for every odd element
  *  it lets you play with vertical align 
  */
  .child:nth-child(odd){
    height: 220px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
jQuery.fn.setMinHeight = function (heightType) {
  'use strict';
  var elems = $(this),
    minHeight = $(elems[0]).height();
  elems.each(function () {
    if (!heightType) {
      if ($(this).height() > minHeight) {
        minHeight = $(this).height();
      }
      $(this).css('min-height', minHeight + 'px');
    } else {
      $(this).css('min-height', heightType);
    }
  });
  if (!heightType) {
    $(elems[0]).css('min-height', minHeight + 'px');
  } else {
    $(elems[0]).css('min-height', heightType);
  }
};
$(some_element).setMinHeight();
$(some_element).setMinHeight('auto');
```